# Serve html dynamically as a static file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, server, static-files

I am trying to serve a directory which includes an index.html file in my Node.js app. The html is for virtual reality and renders with some javascript and three.js files within the directory.I've tried serving the file as a static file when I serve the file with the url "localhost:8080/" with this line of code, it works fine:

```
app2.use('/', express.static('/Users/nancycollins/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/7eef1d1f06439d8612a2409f75f545fb1569088983271/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2'))
```

But as soon as I make it any bit dynamic, it says 'cannot Get'. I also cannot add anything to the url, it only serves it with '/'.

It also works when I add a variable to it like this:

```
const dir = '7eef1d1f06439d8612a2409f75f545fb1569088983271/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2/'
app2.use('/', express.static('/Users/nancycollins/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/${dir}'))
```

But doesnt work at all with URL parameters. I need to be able to serve the whole directory as a static file, as it does not work when i specify the index.html file for some reason.

I wanted the following function to find the path to the file based on the req.param.id (saved to mongodb), with the url "localhost:8080/12345678" but it doesnt work with it as a static file, however it gets the path to the file perfectly:

```
app2.use('/:id', express.static('/Users/nancycollins/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/'))

app2.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  let id = req.params.id
  console.log(id)
  Upload.findById(id)
    .populate('Upload')
    .select('relPath') //relPath = /folder/subfolder
    .exec(function (err, upload) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
          const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')
          const filepath = `${upload.relPath}`
          const fulldir = path.join(dir, filepath)
          fs.readdir(fulldir, function(err, items) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            try {
              for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                  console.log(items[i]);
                  console.log(items.length);
                  var directpath = path.join(fulldir, items[0])
                  console.log(directpath)
                  // req.url = `/${directpath}`
                 // req.url = `${directpath}/index.html` 
                  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: directpath});
              }
            }
            catch (e) {
              console.error(e)
            }
          }
        }) 
        //next()
      }
    })
})
```

This function get the exact same path as the one hard coded in the first and second code examples, but wont work when serving.

I'm really confused about this and getting really stressed about it, I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

I've also tried changing the url in the function rather than res.sendFile, for example

```
req.url = `${directpath}`
```

Nothing will work for me

EDIT:

I've changed it to the following code, which now produces an error saying: "Error: Cannot find module 'html'"

```
app2.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'), options))
const dirfile = '7eef1d1f06439d8612a2409f75f545fb1569088983271/'
app2.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // let id = req.params.id
  // console.log(id)
  // Upload.findById(id)
  //   .populate('Upload')
  //   .select('relPath') //relPath = /folder/subfolder
  //   .exec(function (err, upload) {
  //     if (err) {
  //       console.log(err)
  //     } else {
          const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')
          const filepath = dirfile
          const fulldir = path.join(dir, filepath)
          fs.readdir(fulldir, function(err, items) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            try {
              for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                  console.log(items[i]);
                  console.log(items.length);
                  var directpath = path.join(fulldir, items[0])

                  console.log(directpath)
                  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname + 'uploads/7eef1d1f06439d8612a2409f75f545fb1569088983271/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2'});
                  //express.static(`${directpath}`)
              }
            }
            catch (e) {
              console.error(e)
            }
          }
        }) 
    //   }
    // })
})
```

Comment: We can only help with `express.static()` questions if you give a couple examples of URLs you want to use with the `express.static()` route and then show EXACTLY what the full path is to the file that you want to match with each URL.  Then, and only then, can we advise on how best to set up your `express.static()` route.

Comment: Also, there's NO point at all to using `/:id` with `express.static()` since there's no custom code that would use `req.params.id` in the prebuilt `express.static()` middleware.

Comment: The only url's I want to use with it are /:id as i need to serve the folder depending on the id from mongoose. I have even set up a second express server dedicated to serving these directories as I cannot find any solution for it.

If there's no custom code that would use req.params.id, does that mean I can't use the url to get an id from a DB to specify a route for express.static()?

Comment: I do not understand what that last comment means at all.  Please show the code that gets the "id from mongoose" and then describe in text what that id is used for.  `express.static()` means "static".  It's for URLs that are always the same for all users.  It's not for dynamic URLs that can be different depending upon the circumstance or have some dynamic part to them.